# What do maths grad schools ask for as an update after one graduates from undergrad (US)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics

After getting accepted into a mathematics graduate program (say PhD), what information does the graduate school ask for as an update once one graduates from undergrad (US)? I am aware they ask for a completed official transcript, but do they ask for any other updates, such as status of journal articles submitted and noted in one's application? Do they communicate with one's recommenders at all about the activities of the applicant in the final semester?

I want to know if I can take a sort of break for the semester, and thus what updated information will need to be sent in afterward.

Comment: The purpose of these updates is to check that your record didn't get *worse* than what they saw in your application.  So it makes sense to ask for final grades.  Article status would not be relevant; your publication record can't really get worse.  Even if your submitted article was rejected - to be honest, they probably already assumed that was going to happen.

Answer (score 9):

Successful graduation and transcript are most likely all they need; probably only the former really matters, unless your grades have taken a horrible dive that suggests you aren't prepared to start the program.